# How do I privately ping someone?

Tags: support

I recently received a couple of relatively large bounties from fellow members of this Stack, and I've not known how to thank them for their generosity. I know we don't have a private message feature here. Meanwhile, leaving comments on the answer I gave doesn't seem to be the way to do it, either.

How can I reach out to these people and let them know I appreciate their gesture?

Comment: for readers: [why don't we have private messaging on SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/431/311001)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't know the etiquette or conventions that might otherwise be used here, you can invite them to a semi-private chat.

And upon following @nitsua60's [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/431/311001), there's a link to a related question with a detailed [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57538) which details how to do this.

Precis:

> Go to the [Chat Users Page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users?tab=all&sort=recent) then sort by searching for the desired username. Once you have the chat user, you can 'Start a new room with this user.' The user should be notified with a message in their 'mailbox'. However, don't make this a gallery (no public posting) since the other user will have to request permission to post messages.

Comment: Thanks. I've created the chat room, but now find myself the only one there. I hoped I could use @ to alert him of the room, but as he has never been in this chat before, nothing shows. I fear the room may not be noticed.

Comment: This doesn't work (by design). The only people who can be @'d in chat are those who have already been in that room, and recently. (Private and even semi-private messaging is a deliberate non-feature at SE because [“useful information transmitted privately is unavailable to other readers, subverting the core purpose of the site”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/433/153219).)

Comment: @markovchain Go to [Chat Users Page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users?tab=all&sort=recent "all chat users") then sort by searching for the desired username. Once you have the chat user, you can 'Start a new room with this user.' However it may not notify the user that there's a chat with their name on it. Will test.

Comment: It worked! I did receive a notification, even if you didn't @ me